# Calculating the mean of something that lies between an upper and lower bound in google sheets

Tags: math, google-sheets

This is based on the answer to my question on the StackExchange math site: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1983642/382254

Based on the same example in that question, let is say I have a Google Sheet with the following columns and rows:

```
$0-$10 | $10-$20 | $20-$30
100    | 150     | 80
```

The first row is price range and in those columns in the rows beneath it is the number of products that prices that be any price within the given range.

The question is, how do I apply the calculations in the answer:

[image: Screenshot of equation and calculations]

in Google Sheets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ArrayFormula(
  SUMPRODUCT(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:C1, "\d+"),
             A2:C2) /
  SUM(A2:C2))
```

First we extract the left number of the ranges of the first row with

```
=ArrayFormula(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:C1, "\d+"))
```

Then we sum the products of the extracted numbers with the weights (or counts in this case) to have the sum.

Lastly we divide by the total count.

If you want the right end of the intervals use

```
=ArrayFormula(
  SUMPRODUCT(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:C1, "(\d+)$"),
             A2:C2) /
  SUM(A2:C2))
```

Which just takes extracts the number at the end of each interval string.

Or for the middle of each interval

```
=ArrayFormula(
  SUMPRODUCT((REGEXEXTRACT(A1:C1, "\d+") + REGEXEXTRACT(A1:C1, "\d+$"))/2,
             A2:C2) /
  SUM(A2:C2))
```

Comment: Ok... I am confused... lol :D So, perhaps can you explain first (perhaps even visualise) the error in the calculations in the screenshot?

Comment: Sorry I had an error in my spreadsheet treating the cell as text, that was my mistake

Comment: I was about to comment as I thought I was doing a mistake on my part.

Comment: I'll be in the corner taking care of all that egg in my face

Comment: As in using some notion of mean between the ends of the interval?

Comment: Yes, I mean something like that.

Comment: Like returning both the lower end and the upper end into same cell.

Comment: I just added a formula that does the same for the midpoint of each interval. If you want an upper and lower bound just use the first and second formula and concatenate them with a separator

Comment: Thank you very much. One last question. What do you call this scripting language? Where do I find help/documentation for it in google?

Comment: These are [Google Spreadsheet Formulas](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en), these particular ones used [regular expressions](http://regular-expressions.mobi/index.html). If this helped you please consider accepting the answer. Thanks